# My "Compiling" dialog box has disappeared. Is there a setting to control this?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

The "Compiling" (see screen shot) dialog box no longer pops up when I compile.  Messages are properly showing in the **Messages** window.  And I can click on errors and it goes in code to the error.  I am using Delphi 2007.

Is there a setting/option I may have inadvertently set?  Or maybe an ini file setting to control this?  I tried rebooting the entire computer too and problem still exists.

Everything else is working properly.  But this makes it a very difficult working environment as I don't have visual status if the compiler is done.

NOTE: I am aware of the "automatically close on successful compile" checkbox.  My problem/question is not about the dialog box closing after compile.  It simply never opens at all.

[image: Compiler Message Box]

**Update** @ZdravkoDanev said there is a "Show Compiler progress" toggle on Compiler Options.  I have included screen shot but don't see that.

[image: Delphi Compiler Options]

Comment: this is a valid question. so, +1 to compensate for the downvote you had.

Comment: I upvote any question that was downvoted and no reason was provided for the downvote !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a setting... "Show Compiler progress" under Compiler options.

Comment: I don't see it - I updated post with screen shot of my options.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for the **show compiler progress** option. You need to set this option to true. The Delphi options dialogs have undergone a number of changes over the years and this option has moved from place to place. According to the [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devcommon/environmentoptions_xml.html) for Delphi 2007 you can find it like this:

1. Tools menu.
2. Options.
3. Environment options.
4. Check the **show compiler progress** option.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I wish there was a way split awards.  Technically it looks like Zdravko beat you by a minute.

Comment: I don't think speed is the critical thing but it is absolutely your choice